# PHP - Converting timestamp to ago strange result

Tags: php

I had a working function to convert timestamp to ago. (Ex: 2 minutes ago)
However, today the results are suddenly changed. When I try to convert this timestamp `1502442048` I am getting this result `-978327747` seconds ago.

The first thing that came to my mind is that server administrator could have change the timezone of the server. So I tried to add this to top for setting timezone

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');`

However, nothing has changed. The function was working fine before. What could be the reason for making the function incorrect ?

Here is my ago function

```
function ago($time_ago) {
$time_ago =  strtotime($time_ago) ? strtotime($time_ago) : $time_ago;
$time  = time() - $time_ago;
switch($time):
case $time <= 60;
return ($time == 1) ? '1 second ago' : $time.' seconds ago';
case $time >= 60 && $time < 3600;
return (round($time/60) == 1) ? '1 minute ago' : round($time/60).' minutes ago';
case $time >= 3600 && $time < 86400;
return (round($time/3600) == 1) ? '1 hour ago' : round($time/3600).' hours ago';
case $time >= 86400 && $time < 604800;
return (round($time/86400) == 1) ? '1 day ago' : round($time/86400).' days ago';
case $time >= 604800 && $time < 2600640;
return (round($time/604800) == 1) ? '1 week ago' : round($time/604800).' weeks ago';
case $time >= 2600640 && $time < 31207680;
return (round($time/2600640) == 1) ? '1 month ago' : round($time/2600640).' months ago';
case $time >= 31207680;
return (round($time/31207680) == 1) ? '1 year ago' : round($time/31207680).' years ago' ;
endswitch;
}
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: echo ago("1502442048");

Comment: It's the ternary that creates the problem https://3v4l.org/IDkgX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your ternary to use [**`is_numeric()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
$time_ago =  is_numeric($time_ago) ? $time_ago : strtotime($time_ago);
```

To check if the given time is a unix timestamp, if not, convert it to one.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you actually have to do is to bool cast the ternary.

```
$time_ago = (bool)strtotime($time_ago) ? $time_ago : strtotime($time_ago);
```

So here strtotime will be either true or false and (I swapped order of true/false) strtotime if it's false.